# The function fn:substring is undefined

Tags: substring, taglib

I have a problem with the JSTL tag library prefix "fn" (webapp development in Eclipse Luna).

I have my taglibs.jspf as follows :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"      prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"       prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
```

and web.xml :

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>jspf/taglibs.jspf</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
        <include-prelude>jspf/language_choice.jspf</include-prelude>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

In my jsp page I try to use substring function of JSTL like this :

```
<a href=http://frenchsite.<c:out value="${fn:substring(language, 0, 2)}" />/" class="general-img" >
```

(in order to have link --> http://frenchsite.fr in this case)

and `language_choice.jspf` file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
<fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.myproject.resources.Messages" />
```

but it seems that substring function doesn't work

If I put : `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>`
**at the top** of the page **it works...**

I don't understand, this `taglib` is already defined in `taglibs.jspf` and `taglibs.jspf` imported in all jsp files (see web.xml).

(by the way, fmt prefix don't causes any problems...)

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I directly added those <%@ taglib ~~" lines to the file has problem.
Then error was erased. After I found there were no errors, I deleted those lines again.
Now it looks fine!